# Import WP_Query into script?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I wrote a script for myself but I can't execute it.
First lines in my code:

```
$products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product'
));
```

and there he says:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in 
/var/www/vhosts/gmks/httpdocs/cronjob/after_update.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/gmks/httpdocs/cronjob/after_update.php(7): delold()
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/vhosts/gmks/httpdocs/cronjob/after_update.php on line 10
```

How can I import the `WP_Query Class`?

Greetings and Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've created a cronjob and you're pointing it to a PHP file that references WP_Query outside of the context of the entire WordPress installation.

Rather point the cronjob to something like :
`http://yourdomain.com/?wp_custom_cron=my_custom_action`

Then create a custom WP Plugin with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin name: my custom cron job
 */

add_action( "init", "my_custom_cron_job_check" );
function my_custom_cron_job_check() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) ) {
        if ( $_GET['action']== 'my_custom_action' ) {
            $products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'product'
            ));
            /* do what you need to here */

            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is when you instantiate the `WP_query` Class.
You have to call it like this:

```
$products_IDs = new \WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product'
));
```

or you can also import the class at the top of your script with the 'use', this way:

```
use \WP_Query;
```